# Passing variables while redirecting jsp pages

Tags: jsp

I have three jsp page: annotation.jsp, check.jsp and end.jsp. I am redirecting from check.jsp either to annotation.jsp or to end.jsp based on a condition. While redirecting, I am passing one variable also.

Annotation.jsp:

```
<%@page language="java"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Annotation Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
          String user = request.getParameter("user");
    %>
    <form method="get" action="check.jsp">
        <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<%=user%>">
        <input type="radio" name="similarity" value="Similar"> Similar<br>
        <input type="radio" name="similarity" value="Dissimilar"> Dissimilar<br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Check.jsp:

```
<%@page import="java.io.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get">
        <%
                    String user = request.getParameter("user");
                    if (condition) {
                        String redirectURL1 = "annotation.jsp";
                        response.sendRedirect(redirectURL1);
                    } else {
                        String redirectURL2 = "end.jsp";
                        response.sendRedirect(redirectURL2);
                    }
        %>
   <input type="hidden" name="user" value="<%=user%>">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to know whether this variable is passed or not with this type of redirection? Because I am getting null value in annotation.jsp when coming from check.jsp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line:

```
String redirectURL1 = "annotation.jsp;
response.sendRedirect(redirectURL1);
```

with:

```
String redirectURL1 = "annotation.jsp?User="+request.getParameter("User");
response.sendRedirect(redirectURL1);
```